# How to debug a process developed in C running as a Wi-Fi Access Point?

Tags: wireless, c, debug

I have two processes developed in C. The first one is running as a WiFi Access Point in Ubuntu machine and the second is running as a controller in another Ubuntu machine in the ethernet network. This latter can send configuration commands to the AP. My question is when running this two process and when I send a command from the controller to the AP, how can I debug the AP process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Debugger (remote server)
GDB is a source-level debugger that supports C among other programming languages, capable of breaking programs at any specific line, displaying variable values, and determining where errors occurred.

To install GNU Debugger and GNU Debugger (remote server) in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb gdbserver
```

#### Usage

> 1. gdbserver is launched on the target system, with the arguments:
>
>    - Either a device name (to use a serial line) or a TCP hostname and portnumber, and
>    - The path and filename of the executable to be debugged
>        It then waits passively for the host gdb to communicate with it.
> 2. gdb is run on the host (controller), with the arguments:
>
>    - The path and filename of the executable (and any sources) on the host, and
>    - A device name (for a serial line) or the IP address and port number needed for connection to the target system.

<sub>**Source:** [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver)</sub>